# Call generic within generic with only knowledge of protocol

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Say I have a generic box, and squishable objects. If I put something squishy in the box, then the box, too, can be squished.

```
protocol Squishable {
}

func squish<T: Squishable>(thing: T) {
}

struct Box<T> {
    let content: T
}

//Here's what I'd LIKE to write, but it's not valid code:
extension (Box where T: Squishable): Squishable {
//...so I try this instead...
extension Box: Squishable {
    func hereBeDragons() {
        if content is Squishable {
            squish(content as! Squishable)
            //...but then: "Generic parameter 'T' cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type 'Squishable'"
        }
    }
}
```

I gather my `squish` function wants a *specific* type that happens to be `Squishable`. But it doesn't seem I can give it one, given the circumstances... Is there a workaround? (In this trivial example, obviously we could change `squish` to a non-generic that accepts a protocol, but that's a totally different situation then! The question is what to do with this one.)

**Edit:** As of Xcode 7 beta 2, it seems extensions are more flexible. I can now write this and I think the compiler might know what I mean:

```
extension Box: Squishable where T: Squishable
```

But it sadly responds "Extension of type 'Box' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause". That error seems to explicitly disallow exactly what I wish to do!

Comment: Latest Swift 2.0 Beta (included in Xcode 7 Beta 2) makes your conditional extension on `Box` works. Just minor syntax changes :-)

Comment: @MatteoPiombo: I downloaded it excitedly—I can supply the `where` now, but I have compilation issues when trying to specify protocol conformance. If it's working for you, please write an answer so I can accept!

Comment: I found this..https://twitter.com/jadengeller/status/644735717814349824
Any idea what he means by "write a wrapper struct"?

Comment: Yeah, write a struct implementing the methods you need to use, make it conform to the protocol, then give it a property containing the actual generic and to implement your struct' methods, pass them all on to that property. Good news is that it'll be a temporary workaround because they've planned to add this functionality for Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get it wrong, **Xcote 7 Beta 2** which includes **Swift 2.0 Beta 2** introduce extension conditionals in a way that solves your question:

```
protocol Squishable {
}

func squish(thing: Squishable) {
    print("Squishable")
}

struct Box<T> {
    let content: T
}


extension Box where T: Squishable {
    func hereBeDragons() {
            squish(content)
    }
}

extension Int: Squishable {}
let intBox = Box<Int>(content: 4)
intBox.hereBeDragons()

let stringBox = Box<String>(content: "Foo")
stringBox.hereBeDragons() // Compiler complains since String does not conform to Squishable
```

Please notice this is still **Beta**, so things can change. Anyway I'm pretty confident that the final version will have the feature needed from your question.

Comment: Is there a solution that does not alter the `squish` function?

Comment: You are right that you can call `hereBeDragons()` on `Box` using this solution, but you still cannot pass `Box` to `squish()`--the compiler complains that it isn't `Squishable`, because we never formally declared it to be so.

Comment: Ups beware that `Box` is not a _concrete_ type, it is a _generic_ type. You can't pass `Box` to any function, you alway pass `Box<FooType>`. Anyway, you could consider updating your question taking into account the latest Swift 2.0 additions. And that you will consider a Swift 2.0 answer since, of course, my answer is not valid for Swift 1.2 and earlier.